# TimeChart scroll (navigate) to specific X value after app starts up

Tags: achartengine

I'm trying to solve problem:

TimeChartView should be scrolled (navigate) to specific X axis value after app startup.

I'm trying to use ChartView.scrollTo (X, 0)  and  mChartView.setX(X)
But it works not like it was to be expected.
It's looks like ChartView moved by itself in layout instead of scroll.

Where is my mistake? Any other more suitable solution for this case?
Here is my code:

1) layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:background="#000000"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chartx"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFAA00" <---------- ORANGE PART OF SCREEN, u can see on screenshot
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

2) activity

```
lChart = (LinearLayout) mapV.findViewById(R.id.chartx);

if (mChartView != null) {
    lChart.removeView(mChartView);
}

mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(mapActivity, mDataset, mRenderer, "dd/MMM/yy");

mChartView.scrollTo(100, 0);

lChart.addView(mChartView, 0, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

mChartView.repaint();
```

3) Data

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {

            c.set(c.MILLISECOND, 0);
            c.set(c.SECOND, 0);
            c.set(c.MINUTE, 0);
            c.set(c.HOUR, 0);

            time_series.add(new Date(value + i*cTimeChart.DAY), 0);

        }
```

Let's say we are adding 90 values but we want our scrollable ChartView will be opened (visible) on value 45.

That's what I want to get to.

Here my screenshot
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42675740/Screenshot.png 
background="#FFAA00" - Orange part of screen, looks like ChartView moved inside layout.
And what I'm expecting - dates should be scrolled instead of view moving.

BTW. I'm using achartengine-1.1.0

Comment: Can you show the code which is failing? Or perhaps use something else to better illustrate what is happening unlike expected.

Comment: All details was attached in my original question. Any suggestion? What I'm doing wrong?